# Flask render two templates back to back

Tags: python, flask

Is it possible to render mutliple html sites in one route? I want my current site to display another message but then to disappear when another site is called.

Like below:

```
    return render_template("index.html", message="hello")
    return render_template("menu.html")
```

Another possibility to solve my problem would be to start another route from the current route. I also did not find this possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you mean but the short answer is "no".
You cannot user two return statement in a route but what you can do is a redirect after the message appears.

The message would not reappear on your second html since you didn't include a message.

```
return render_template("menu.html")
```

Comment: What is meant by ,,redirect after the message appears"? In your example only menu.html is rendered. I want my Index site to display a message for example for 3 seconds and then to disappear.